# How to break div id text after n number of characters in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I trying to break long text.

The text look like this: `Inquire about space/Enter Library`. The text is currently separated using the slash. So we can use the / to tell the code where to break though I don't mind using character count to break the text (preferable) because the text doesn't change. The div containing this text is referenced by the id `#npali`

Output should look like this

`Inquire about space<br>
Enter Library`

I am unable to get this to work. I was wondering if a PHP alternative would be available to help me achieve this.

Please help if you might know the fix.

Comment: Everything you need is in the [String functions manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)... Read.

Comment: _“I am unable to get this to work.”_ - even in such a case, you are expected to show what you have tried. Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the `explode()` See more: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

An example:

```
function slash2br($str){
  $parts = explode("/", $str);
  return implode("<br>", $parts);
}
```

You could also `preg_replace()` and replace the `/` with `<br>`.

Comment: Why not str_replace btw? Just curious.

Comment: @EbrahimMohammed would work well too, I just didn't think of it.